# Iterate over a list of list to create a new list of list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I think I understand what need to be done. However I can't get the results right. I have a list of lists with several items. I want to create a new list(with more elements, based on a criteria) but keeping length of the original list of lists. Let's exemplify:

```
test = [[2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24, 25], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 23, 24]] # there are hundreds of lists in the original list
list_num_sor = []
new_list = []
for row in test:
    for i in range(1, 26):
        if i in row:
            new_list.append('1')
        else:
            new_list.append('0')
    list_num_sor.append(new_list)
```

What I'm trying to do is, for each list in test, I want to validate if in a range 1-25, this number is in the list, returning 1, otherwise, 0. The original list has 15 elements, the new one should have 25.

The result should be:

```
 list_num_sor = [['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
                ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0']]
```

But what I'm getting is a list of lists, where each element has the results of all the items from the first list of list:

```
 [['0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0'],
  ['0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '0']]
```

Hope I could make it understandable. I need it to be a list of lists to create a DF afterwards. I don't think processing time would be a problem as it is not something big enough for it to become a problem.

Hope you people could help me out.

Thanks

​

Comment: You'll want to move `new_list = []` into the body of your first for-loop. Otherwise, you are constantly appending to the same list reference, and then appending the same list reference to your `list_num_sor` list.

Comment: Note that there is only *one single* ``new_list = []`` in this code. *All* elements get appended to it, and in return this single list is appended to ``list_num_sor`` again and again for each row.

Comment: I don't understand your criteria

Comment: I tried to put `new_list = []` in the second for loop but didn't try in the first. Now it is working. Thanks @PaulM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a new list for every row in your old list:

```
for row in test:
    new_list.append([])
    for i in range(1, 26):
        if i in row:
            new_list[-1].append('1')
        else:
            new_list[-1].append('0')
```

Every iteration add a list to your list of lists, and then append the 0/1 values to the last list added (`[-1]`). More concisely:

```
new_list = [[1 if i in row else 0 for i in range(1, 26)] for row in test]
```

This has the added benefit you can just put it in your call to the `DataFrame`  constructor directly.

Comment: I see. It's a simpler way than the one mentioned in the comments on the question as it only need one new list. I really should try to my hands in the list comprehension method more often. Thanks @kabanus

Comment: @GustavoRottgering The amount of lists are the same at the end, only the amount of code is different as in syntactic sugar (well, also it's better with performance).